# How can I open a google chrome control in C#

Tags: c#

I know there is a way to add a IE control, how do you add a chrome control...? Is it even possible right now?

I'm need this because of the fast javascript VM found in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched around and I don't think Google Chrome registers itself as a Windows COM+ component.  I think you're out of luck.

Comment: IE uses a COM wrapper but .NET doesn't need COM, it can use P/Invoke.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: [Use chrome as browser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2141668/258482)

Answer (score 1):

IE control is actually ActiveX component - so it can be wrapped in .Net component. It is not real IE, it's mainly only its rendering engine (HTML+CSS+JS) plus web client (HTTP and some more protocols) Control itself has no menu, bookmarks etc. Chrome is full featured browser. So you should be asking for WebKit (rendering engine chrome use, developed by Safari's guys) control.

There is an outdated Mozilla ActiveX (actually Gecko rendering engine). It's much more complicated to use and only available as ActiveX, no native .Net/C#.

Comment: Actually, Chrome's browser engine is inclusive of V8 (the Javascript engine), which is not included in WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it yourself... Chrome is based on the open source webkit rendering engine.  Good luck though, I'm pretty sure it's not managed code friendly.