# Use Chrome engine in WebBrowser control WinForms

Tags: winforms, google-chrome, webkit, webbrowser-control

Can you use Chrome Web Browser webkit engine  in WebBrowser control in WindowsForms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141668/use-chrome-as-browser-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use chrome's webkit as a *different* webbrowser component, as answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142184/is-there-an-embeddable-webkit-component-for-windows-c-sharp-development) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790542/replacing-net-webbrowser-control-with-a-better-browser-like-chrome). I suggest you to read the answers already posted here on SO as they contain really good clues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [WebKit](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/). Chrome it self is not a COM and can't be used directly AFAIK