# How to use browser chrome in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

im newbie and learn in vb.net 2010

i ve plan to create simple browser using vb.net
this code

```
  Form2.WebBrowser2.Navigate("http://xxxxx.com")
```

for now . detect browser mozilla firefox with gecko 
this tutorial 
http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/wiki/GettingStarted

can you help me how to detect browser chrome when im use tbrowser in vb.net ?

thanks
jk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Chrome engine in WebBrowser control WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983787/use-chrome-engine-in-webbrowser-control-winforms)

Answer (score -2):

do

```
webbrowser1.setdefaultbrowser("chrome.google.browserid")
```