# Custom Web Browser control with support of new CSS3 features

Tags: c#, .net, browser, wrapper

I'm looking a custom web browser control for .net framework.

There is bunch of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141668/use-chrome-as-browser-in-c), but they are old and can't run new CSS3 features smoothly (or they simply can't!). For example, [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) and [Webkit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) are available but they can't run animations/transitions hardware-accelerated.

But, new web browsers (Chrome 21, Firefox 15) are supporting these new features smooth and hardware-accelerated.

Is there any .Net Web Brower control with support of new HTML5/CSS3 features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really don't need CEF1/3 why not to try [GeckoFX](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx) control?
It's quite gentle, supports css3, html5 with audio/video tags, webgl and the project seems to be active developed.

Answer (score 6):

You can always [use chromium from .NET](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). Chromium support latest features. The Chromium Embedded Framework ([CEF](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)) is an open source project to develop a Web browser control based on the Google Chromium project. There's a .NET version already [working](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp) (CEF1), you can implement it, not easy but definitively possible, see the link provided for the specific documentation.

Also, there is a [CEF3 wrapper for .Net](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home), you can download the binaries [under the official forums](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=14).

*CEF3 Supports 3D while CEF1 not.*

***Update:*** You can download latest binaries of CEF3 wrapper from [here](http://xilium.bitbucket.org/cefglue/).

Comment: Can you explain more? Can those binaries added to a C# application?

Comment: Seems that it doesn't support 3D. Is there any way to enable it? or is there any other libraries?

Comment: Is there any CEF3 Wrapper for .Net?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Sure there is for .NET & Mono at https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home

Comment: @RandolfRF I can't find binaries/examples anywhere, can you give me the exact link, or upload them somewhere?

Comment: I'm working with CEF3 wrapper, sample is in C++ language, and I haven't any idea about using it in c#. Do you know how to use it in c#?

Comment: Please notice, that CEF1 do not supports HTML5 <video> <audio> tags and CEF3 for C# (I mean Xilium.Glue - I had no problem with CEF1) is hard to obtain (a lot of black boxes native code). I tried to compile CEF3 but I always stuck on libcef.init method - just nothing happend probably I did something wrong, but after few days of trying I just gived up.