# System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser, System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher, and a windows service

Tags: wpf, windows-services, webbrowser-control, dispatcher

I'm trying to render some html content to a bitmap in a Windows Service.

I'm using System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser to perform the render.  The basic rendering setup works as a standalone process with a WPF window hosting the control, but as a service, at least I'm not getting the LoadCompleted events to fire.

I know that I at least need a Dispatcher or other message pump looping for this WPF control.  Perhaps I'm doing it right and there are just additional tricks/incompatibilities necessary for the WebBrowser control.  Here's what I've got:

I believe only one Dispatcher needs to be running and that it can run for the life of the service.  I believe the Dispatcher.Run() is the actual loop itself and thus needs it's own thread which it can otherwise block.  And that thread needs to be `[STAThread]` in this scenario.  Therefore, in a relevant static constructor, I have the following:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    Dispatcher.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

where `dispatcher` is a static field.  Again, I think there can only be one but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be able use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher()` from anywhere instead and get the right reference.

The rendering operation is as follows.  I create, navigate, and dispose of the `WebBrowser` on `dispatcher`'s thread, but event handler assignments and `mres.Wait` I think may all happen on the render request-handling operation.  I had gotten `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it` but now with this setup I don't.

```
WebBrowser wb = null;
var mres = new ManualResetEventSlim();

try
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(() => { wb = new WebBrowser(); });

    wb.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        // Not firing
    };

    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            sw.Write(html);
            sw.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // GO!
            dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    wb.NavigateToStream(ms);
                    Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread) != null);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // log
                }
            });

            if (!mres.Wait(15 * 1000)) throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log
    }
}
finally
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(() => { if (wb != null) wb.Dispose(); });
}
```

When I run this, I get my timeout exception every time since the LoadCompleted never fires.  I've tried to verify that the dispatcher is running and pumping properly.  Not sure how to do that, but I hooked a few of the dispatcher's events from the static constructor and I get some printouts from that, so I think it's working.

The code does get to a `wb.NavigateToStream(ms);` breakpoint.

Is this bad application of Dispatcher?  Is the non-firing of wb.LoadCompleted due to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: `wb.LoadCompleted` doesn't get fired because you add this event handler from a different thread the WebBrowser object was created on. Try moving it inside  `dispatcher.Invoke(() => { .. })` delegate. That still might not be a nice design, but at least the even should be getting fired.

Comment: @Noseratio - Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't think that it is a requirement that the event handler needs to be added on the same thread but I just tried it but it doesn't allow the event to fire - no change.  Once I get it working I'll try with and without just to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code which works as a console app. A few points:

- You need a parent window for WPF WebBrowser. It may be a hidden window like below, but it has to be physically created (i.e. have a live HWND handle). Otherwise, WB never finishes loading the document (`wb.Document.readyState == "interactive"`), and `LoadCompleted` never gets fired. I was not aware of such behavior and it is different from the WinForms version of WebBrowser control. May I ask why you picked WPF for this kind of project?
- You do need to add the `wb.LoadCompleted` event handler on the same thread the WB control was created (the dispatcher's thread here). Internally, WPF WebBrowser is just a wrapper around apartment-threaded WebBrowser ActiveX control, which exposes its events via `IConnectionPointContainer` interface. The rule is, all calls to an apartment-threaded COM object must be made on (or proxied to) the thread the object was originally created on, because that's what such kind of objects expect. In that sense, `IConnectionPointContainer` methods are no different to other methods of WB.
- A minor one, `StreamWriter` automatically closes the stream it's initialized with (unless explicitly told to not do so in the constructor), so there is no need to for wrapping the stream with `using`.

The code is ready to compile and run (it requires some extra assembly references: PresentationFramework, WindowsBase, System.Windows, System.Windows.Forms, Microsoft.mshtml).

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using mshtml;    

namespace ConsoleWpfApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static Dispatcher dispatcher = null;
        static ManualResetEventSlim dispatcherReady = new ManualResetEventSlim();

        static void StartUIThread()
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Debug.Print("UI Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                try
                {
                    dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                    dispatcherReady.Set();
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Print("UI Thread exception: {0}", ex.ToString());
                }
                Debug.Print("UI Thread exits");
            });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

        static void DoWork()
        {
            Debug.Print("Worker Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            dispatcherReady.Wait(); // wait for the UI tread to initialize

            var mres = new ManualResetEventSlim();
            WebBrowser wb = null;
            Window window = null; 

            try
            {    
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.Unicode)) // StreamWriter automatically closes the steam
                {
                    sw.Write("<b>Hello, World!</b>");
                    sw.Flush();
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    // GO!
                    dispatcher.Invoke(() => // could do InvokeAsync here as then we wait anyway
                    {
                        Debug.Print("Invoke Thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                        // create a hidden window with WB
                        window = new Window()
                        {
                            Width = 0,
                            Height = 0,
                            Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden,
                            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                            ShowInTaskbar = false,
                            ShowActivated = false
                        };
                        window.Content = wb = new WebBrowser();
                        window.Show();
                        // navigate
                        wb.LoadCompleted += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Debug.Print("wb.LoadCompleted fired;");
                            mres.Set(); // singal to the Worker thread
                        };
                        wb.NavigateToStream(ms);
                    });

                    // wait for LoadCompleted
                    if (!mres.Wait(5 * 1000))
                        throw new TimeoutException();

                    dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {   
                        // Show the HTML
                        Console.WriteLine(((HTMLDocument)wb.Document).documentElement.outerHTML);
                    });    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
                {
                    if (window != null)
                        window.Close();
                    if (wb != null) 
                        wb.Dispose();
                });
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartUIThread();
            DoWork();
            dispatcher.InvokeShutdown(); // shutdown UI thread
            Console.WriteLine("Work done, hit enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. I'm sure you have your reasons to use WPF for this, but it'd probably take less resources if done with WinForms's WebBrowser. Or, perhaps, it'd be more appropriate to use [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com), which is tailored for off-screen rendering.

Comment: Yay!  It works!  Thanks!  Yeah, this may go to Awesomium but this is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Webbrowser Control needs Desktop Interaction for rendering the content:

[image]

My feeling say that using WPF controls and in particular particulary the Webbrowser-Control (=Wrapper around the IE ActiveX control) isn't the best idea.. There are other rendering engines that might be better suited for this task: [Use chrome as browser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141668/use-chrome-as-browser-in-c)

Comment: Hi Martin.  I'm not even running it as a service yet, really.  It can be run that way but for now I'm just running it as a user process under my credentials with ServiceBase harness - so it should already have that access (for now).  I'll investigate using Chrome too but it'd be nice to figure this one out first.